# Unable to create Cloud SQL Instance

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to create a new Cloud SQL instance to go along with my already created Compute Engine VM.

Each time I click the confirm button, the creation fails with the following message:

*Could not create a new Cloud SQL Instance.*

Billing is set up, as I can create other services (such as Compute).

I'm trying to set up an SQL instance in the United States, MySQL 5.5, D1 - Daily, us-central-1a (same as compute), and with the IP of the compute allowed to access it.

I've tried lots of combinations and keep getting this same error in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Turns out it wouldn't create with an IP address allowed to access it.  I removed the IP of the compute engine, and I was able to create the SQL instance.

Comment: Hi there, I haven't been able to replicate this using the steps you gave. If you are able to replicate it, please email us at cloud-sql@google.com and we'll try to figure out what's up.

Answer (score 0):

same issue here with the Authorized App Engine Applications automatically filled with my project name... After removing the applications from this form, the creation is successful.

Comment: I tried removing the project app from "AUTHORIZED APP ENGINE APPLICATIONS" but I still get the issue.  Is this what you were referring to?